# Jupyter notebook equivalent of MATLAB's stackedplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Per subject... I'm looking for a way to get a stacked plot of several variables with common x-axis into a Jupyter notebook. *Not* a stackplot; that's different.

Example here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stackedplot.html

Comment: Those are called *subplots*.

Comment: @lotatron How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland Nicely, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a set of three vertically stacked  interactive [subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) using plotly in a Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, 
                    shared_xaxes=True, 
                    vertical_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]),
              row=3, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600,
                  title_text="Stacked Subplots with Shared X-Axes")
fig.show()
```